How to refresh frontend cache automatically for a React webapp built with Vite
I hope this thread finds a kind soul that could help me lol
I have a React webapp that I build with Vite : tsc && vite build
Each time I do an update on that frontend, I increase the minor version of the app in the package.json (ex: from 1.8.0 to 1.9.0). The problem is that a lot of times, I have to clear my browser's cache to get the new app version (tried with firefox and chrome). My client also calls me and I always tell him to clear the browser's cache and refresh... Does anyone know how to fix this ? I thought that by simply increasing the version in package.json and triggering a new build it would do the trick but apparently not.
More context:

I checked the "minified" js files on my browser and they have a hash behind the names and that hash changes with a new build.
I use ingress-nginx to serve the frontend webapp.

Tried: Increasing the package.json version and trigger a new build.
Expected: Not having to clear the browser's cache to get the new version of the app

No one has a clue ? im still struggling on this issue... :(((((
